# Rake db actions get an EOF error in read_nonblock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, activerecord

I'm setting up a local copy of an inherited Rails 4 app (Ruby 2.0.0p645) with a Postgres database. The database works fine on its own, and migrations go through without problems, but `rake db:seed`, `db:load`, `db:dump`, and `db:purge` all throw the same error.

```
~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:153:in `read_nonblock': end of file reached (EOFError)
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:153:in `rbuf_fill'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:134:in `readuntil'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:144:in `readline'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:307:in `read_chunked'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:276:in `block in read_body_0'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:269:in `inflater'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:274:in `read_body_0'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:201:in `read_body'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:226:in `body'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:163:in `reading_body'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1418:in `block in transport_request'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1409:in `catch'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1409:in `transport_request'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1382:in `request'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/net_http_ext.rb:51:in `request'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `block in request'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1373:in `request'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/net_http_ext.rb:51:in `request'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/httparty-0.12.0/lib/httparty/request.rb:93:in `perform'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/httparty-0.12.0/lib/httparty.rb:486:in `perform_request'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/httparty-0.12.0/lib/httparty.rb:439:in `post'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/httparty-0.12.0/lib/httparty.rb:522:in `post'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/runtimeerror_notifier-0.0.18/lib/runtimeerror_notifier/notifier.rb:46:in `make_request'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/runtimeerror_notifier-0.0.18/lib/runtimeerror_notifier/notifier.rb:39:in `notification'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__295926636__process_action__callbacks'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionmailer-4.0.3/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:503:in `process'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionmailer-4.0.3/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:497:in `initialize'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionmailer-4.0.3/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:480:in `new'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionmailer-4.0.3/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:480:in `method_missing'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/runtimeerror_notifier-0.0.18/lib/runtimeerror_notifier/rake_handler.rb:13:in `display_errors_with_runtimeerror'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:174:in `rescue in standard_exception_handling'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
from ~/Code/dbSeer/docufyi/bin/rake:4:in `<main>'
```

I find this quite confusing, especially since all mentions I can find of EOF errors involving `read_nonblock` involve HTTP requests, and I can't find any reason why these database tasks should be involving that at all.

Any idea why these HTTP gems might be getting involved?

My entire `database.yml`, which seems potentially relevant:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: docufyi_development
  username: postgres
  host: 127.0.0.1
  password:
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
```

(Suggestions for common gems that use `httparty` or `rest-client` also appreciated.)

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '4.0.3'

gem 'aasm'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'
gem 'awesome_print'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.9.0'
gem 'cells'
gem 'cocoon'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'country_select'
gem 'dalli'
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_invitable', '~> 1.3.2'
gem 'email_validator'
gem 'entypo-rails'
gem 'faker', '~> 1.2.0'
gem 'figaro', '~> 0.7.0'
gem 'fog', '~> 1.18.0'
gem 'grim', '~> 0.3.0'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'high_voltage', '~> 2.0.0'
gem 'icalendar', '~> 1.4.4'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-themes'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'memcachier'
gem 'mobile-fu'
gem 'money-rails'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'paper_trail', '~> 3.0.2'
gem 'pg'
gem 'polar-express', :git => 'https://github.com/danielboggs/polar-express.git'
gem 'pry-rails'
gem 'pundit', :git => 'https://github.com/elabs/pundit.git'
gem 'redcarpet'
gem 'runtimeerror_notifier'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'sidekiq', '~> 2.16.1'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'simple-form-datepicker'
gem 'stripe', '~> 1.9.9'
gem 'stripe_event'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'mimemagic'
gem 'unf'
gem 'user_impersonate2', :require => 'user_impersonate'
gem 'webshims-rails'
gem 'whenever', :require => false

# use vPim for vCard Uploader
gem 'vpim', '~> 13.11.11'

# use font-awesome icons
gem "font-awesome-rails"

group :development do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'hirb'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'thin'
 # uses mailcatcher
end

group :production, :staging do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.1.1'
  gem 'email_spec'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.2.1'
  gem 'json_spec'
  gem 'rspec-cells'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 2.4.0'
  gem 'spreewald'
  gem 'utensils'
  gem 'webrat'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the initializers?, apparently the problem has to do with a the RestClient gem. Are you using it by any chance?.

Comment: Not directly, no. Presumably some gem I am using hooks it in as a dependency, but the project is using ~140 gems and I'd rather not search through them for a reference to this.

Comment: And again, my DB is local and I have no idea how http requests are coming into the picture in the first place.

Comment: Can you provide your Gemfile?